# What's wrong with my conditional?

Tags: python, conditional-statements

I have this code:

```
    listOfColumns = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"]
    validChoice = False
    if color1 == "White":
        piece = raw_input(self.Player1["Name"] + ", pick a piece to move. Enter the coordinates (ex. A3, D4, etc.)." + "\n")
        while validChoice == False:
            column = self.position_to_xCoor(piece)
            row = self.position_to_yCoor(piece)
            piece1 = self.Chessboard.Matrix[row][column].Piece
            print piece1.Color
            print color1
            if str(piece[0]) != any(self.listOfColumns) or int(piece[1]) > 8 or piece1.Color != color1:
                piece = raw_input("That is not a valid choice. Pick again." + "\n")
            else:
                validChoice = True
```

where Chessboard is an object of another class that has the attribute Piece, which has the attribute color. The user is meant to enter the coordinates (ie. A2, B3, D7). But why do I keep getting this result? I thought all of my conditionals were met.

```
White
White
That is not a valid choice. Pick again.
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not how `any()` works. The result of `any()` is `True` or `False`, while a `str()` of something will return a string, not a boolean. You need the `in` operator:

```
if str(piece[0]) not in self.listOfColumns or...
```

Comment: @VictorMao: If an answer is helpful, please accept it. Check our [tour] and [help] for more details.